# If one distribution stochastically dominates another one, can we prove something for the minimum?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

assume that I have a distribution $F(\cdot)$ that stochastically dominates another distribution $G(\cdot)$. Therefore, two conditions hold

1. $\int_a^b F(w) \, dw = \int_a^b G(w) \, dw$
2. $\int_a^W F(w) \, dw<\int_a^W G(w) \, dw$ for all $w\in (a,b)$

We know that the if I have $N$ iid draws from each distribution, the distribution of the respective minima is given by

$$ H_F(w) = 1-[1-F(w)]^N $$
$$ H_G(w) = 1-[1-G(w)]^N $$

Using $(2),$ one can show that

$$ \int_a^W (1-G(w)) \, dw < \int_a^W (1-F(w)) \, dw $$

Does this imply that,

$$ \int_a^W (1-G(w))^N \, dw < \int_a^W (1-F(w))^N \, dw \text{?} $$

Comment: Can one just say that the Nth power of a function is just an increasing transformation and therefore the inequality must hold?